# convert docker run command to kubectl for one time execution

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minio

I'm trying to run a docker image once to execute a task using a popular [S3 client minio](https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/mc/) the environment I'm dealing with use Kubernetes.

I can get shell access to execute tasks like so:

```
docker run -it minio/mc --restart=Never --rm /bin/sh
```

similarly, I'm able to run busybox image in my K8S cluster.

```
kubectl run busybox -i --tty --image=busybox --restart=Never --rm -- sh
```

However, I'm unable to get that mc client to work the same way it does with the previous example.

```
kubectl run minio -i --tty  --image=minio/mc --restart=Never --rm --  /bin/sh
```

My shell would just exit, any ideas on how to keep the shell open? or how to pass bash commands to it before it dies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue arises when container(s) in a Pod run some process(es) that complete. When its containers exit, the Pod completes. It is more common to have container(s) in a Pod that run continuously.

A solution to this completing problem is thus to keep the container running:

1. Run the container in a Pod:

```sh
kubectl run minio \
--image=minio/mc \
--restart=Never \
--command \
--  /bin/sh -c 'while true; do sleep 5s; done'
```

> **NOTE** the Pod is kept running by the `while` loop in the container

> **NOTE** the image's entrypoint is overridden by `--command` and `/bin/sh`

2. Exec into the container, e.g.:

```sh
kubectl exec --stdin --tty minio -- mc --help
```